# Как заблокировать экран при нажатии определенной кнопки

Tags: java, android

У меня есть страница входа, после нажатия кнопки "Войти" мне нужно временно заблокировать экран до получения ответа от сервера.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы можете просто отобразить оверлей с индикатором прогресса поверх всех остальных `View`, главное, не забудьте сделать его кликабильным (`android:clickable="true"`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/progressBarOverlay"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@color/overlay_grey"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

В этом примере `FrameLayout` -- это контейнер всех остальных элементов на странице, а `RelativeLayout` c id `progressBarOverlay` -- полупрозрачный оверлей (прозрачность регулируется цветом `@color/overlay_grey`). В нужный момент просто сделайте оверлей видимым `progressBarOverlay.setVisisbility(View.VISISBLE)`, а затем измените значение обратно на `View.GONE`, чтобы убрать оверлей.

Comment: Спасибо ,то что я искал!